# Objective C- iCal not creating custom calendar and new event to it in iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios9, icalendar

This working perfectly in iOS 8.

But creating issue in iOS 9.Here is code :

```
self.eventManager.eventStore requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (granted) {

            // Create a new calendar.
            EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent
                                                          eventStore:self.eventManager.eventStore];

            // Set the calendar title.
            calendar.title = @"<APP name>";
            calendar.CGColor=APP_Blue_COLOR.CGColor;

            // Find the proper source type value.
            for (int i=0; i<self.eventManager.eventStore.sources.count; i++) {
                EKSource *source = (EKSource *)[self.eventManager.eventStore.sources objectAtIndex:i];
                EKSourceType currentSourceType = source.sourceType;

                if (currentSourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal) {
                    calendar.source = source;
                    break;
                }
            }


            // Save and commit the calendar.
            NSError *error;
            [self.eventManager.eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];

            // If no error occurs then turn the editing mode off, store the new calendar identifier and reload the calendars.
            if (error == nil) {
                // Turn off the edit mode.
                // Store the calendar identifier.
                [self.eventManager saveCustomCalendarIdentifier:calendar.calendarIdentifier];self.eventManager.selectedCalendarIdentifier=calendar.calendarIdentifier;//chirag

            }
            else{
                // Display the error description to the debugger.
                NSLog(@"CREATE_CALENDER %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }

        }
        else
        {

            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"" message:@"Please give permission to access your iPhone calender." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];


        }

    }];
```

It give me success message but not creating my app calendar in iPhone calendar.

I though that it does not showing it due to no event set to it.so I also tried to set new event.

But it give me following code & error while creating new event.

```
// Create a new event object.
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:self.eventManager.eventStore];

    // Set the event title.
    event.title = title;

    // Set its calendar.
    event.calendar = [self.eventManager.eventStore calendarWithIdentifier:self.eventManager.selectedCalendarIdentifier];

    // Set the start and end dates to the event.
    event.startDate = startDate;
    event.endDate = endDate;
 // Save and commit the event.
    NSError *error;
    if ([self.eventManager.eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error]) {
        // Call the delegate method to notify the caller class (the ViewController class) that the event was saved.
        return true;
    }
    else{
        // An error occurred, so log the error description.
        NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    return false;
    }
```

It give following error internally however it return will in NSError object:

```
Error getting shared calendar invitations for entity types 3 from daemon: Error Domain=EKCADErrorDomain Code=1014 "(null)"
```

Comment: Experiencing the same issue. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that when iCloud calendars switched on, it hides the locally created ones from the calendar app. To bypass this problem the solution is to add a new calendar to iCloud source:

```
for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources)
{
    if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV && 
       [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"]) //This is a patch.
    {
        localSource = source;
        break;
    }
}

if (localSource == nil)
{
    for (EKSource *source in self.eventStore.sources)
    {
        if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal)
        {
            localSource = source;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```